# How to Implement Swipe Image inside Collapsing toolbar android

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to make the image view Swipable inside the collapsing toolbar. Can someone please point me to some reference link or give me and example which will make me swipe images insider the collapsible toolbar.
for example from the server i will get 4 images , i want user to swipe and look all images.. please help

Below is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinateLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.navact.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="300dip"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/side_nav_bar" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/backdrop"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can implement this feature by replacing your imageview with a viewPager inside your collapsingToolbarLayout as shown below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/viewPager_height"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

One thing what you have to keep in mind is that, if you give your **viewPager** **height** as **wrap_content**, it will not collapse vertically, so always provide a **FIXED** height to viewPager

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewPager instead of ImageView.Take a look at this [example](http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/) for ViewPager

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="300dip"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: I have almost followed the code in example and created a custom adapter, but the custom adapter requires the image view and a view pager.... check these lines.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

Comment: so if i remove image view , the same code wont work , thats the problem i am facing

Comment: Yes. follow the example and use the view pager and imageview. You will achieve what you want.

Comment: where should i keep image view ?

Comment: ImageView should be in a separate layout file in your layout folder.